# Update scope variable from $http.get on JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having an issue with a $scope variable not updated :

In my controller I have :

```
$scope.frCartoList = [];
$scope.enCartoList = [];
$scope.cartoList = [];
$scope.filteredCartoList = [];

$scope.loadJSON = function () {
        $http.get("SVG/fr/cartoList.json")
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.frCartoList = data;
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log("Error while getting french json.");
            });

        $http.get("SVG/en/cartoList.json")
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.enCartoList = data;
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log("Error while getting english json.");
            });
        $scope.setDefaultSearch();
        $scope.getAreaFilters();
        $scope.getBlockFilters();

        if ($scope.shared)
            $scope.homeVisible = false;
        console.log($scope.enCartoList);
    };

    $scope.setJSON = function () {
        if ($scope.isEnglish)
            $scope.cartoList = $scope.enCartoList;
        else if ($scope.isFrench)
            $scope.cartoList = $scope.frCartoList;

        console.log($scope.enCartoList);

        $scope.initMenu();
        $scope.filteredCartoList = $scope.cartoList.filter($scope.search);
    };

$scope.loadJSON();
$scope.setJSON();
```

But my `$scope.enCartoList` and my `$scope.frCartoList` have the proper value only inside the `$http.get`
I suppose, this is not the main `$scope` that is used or something, but that's weird, because before that I had only one `$scope.cartoList` I used to set in the `$scope.loadJSON` and it was updated in the whole controller...

Comment: Place your console logs inside the success methods and you'll get values. It's asynch so success is executed when the server reply, not straight away.

Comment: please use $timeout
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: @Arvaan $timeout is not applicable to trying to access asynchronous response

Comment: @gillesc I did place my console inside the success, but I want to make this variable accessible from anywhere in the controller.
@ Arvaan Why would I need to use $timeout ?

Comment: Would be  simpler to use `$scope.isEnglish` to determine which data url is needed and only have one `$http`... then do all processing in success callback

Comment: I need both objects for my other treatments, so the question is I guess how to modify the main $scope variable from the $http.get().success ?

Comment: You are only using one language at a time aren't you? If you must have both of those together use `$q.all(requestEnglish,requestFrench)`

Comment: I am using one language at a time, but I can't afford to load the json everytime I change language. And I need data from both languages JSON anyway . 
$q.all should be used in the loadJSON and contain the get function ?

Comment: no.. `$q.all( $http('english'), $http('french')).then(...`

Comment: if using UI-router could also use `resolve` in main app state to return these requests before controller is initialized

Comment: You can use $scope.$watch and assign once results returned.

Comment: `angular.copy(response, $scope.frCartoList);`